# Matching on content-type

Tags: dictionary

I am trying to use the nginx map module to detect if the Content-Type being passing into the request is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  My sample regex code in the map is not working.  Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
map $content_type $ct {
    ~^/application\/x-www-form-urlencoded/ "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    default "application/json";
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Content-Type $ct;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not using the map function at all, instead:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    location / {
        set $ct "application/json";
        if ($content_type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") {
            set $ct "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        } 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Content-Type $ct;
    }
}
```